# Javascript select all on dropdown with checkbox and search

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I have a checkbox dropdown that has a search and select all.
They both work great, the thing is when i search, i would like the select all to only select all the displayed checkboxes, right now after a search and i click select all it still selects every box.

Here is my html

```
<div id="dropdownSearch" class="hidden bg-white rounded-lg shadow w-60" style="z-index: 999;">
<div class="p-3">
    <label for="input-group-search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5 " placeholder="Search user">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="ml-4 flex items-center p-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-100">
        <input id="checkbox-item-14" onchange="selectAll()" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500">
        <label for="checkbox-item-14" id="select_all" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded dark:text-gray-300">Select All</label>
    </div>
<ul id="getMerchant" class="h-48 px-3 pb-3 overflow-y-auto text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownSearchButton">
    @foreach($mids as $mid)
        <li>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="flex items-center p-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 ">
                <input id="merchant" name="merchant[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$mid->mid_id}}" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 ">
                <label for="merchant-checkbox" id="merchant_name" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded ">{{$mid->mid_name}}</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
<script>
    function filterFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        console.log(filter);
        div = document.getElementById("getMerchant");
        a = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                a[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                a[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    function selectAll(){
        if($('#checkbox-item-14').is(':checked')){
            var ele = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
            for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
                ele[i].checked = true;
            }
        }else{
            var ele = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
            for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
                ele[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the *Select All* option when searching, consider starting the `for` loop from index `1`, so that it skips the first `<li>`, the `<li>` that contains the *Select All* option:

```js
for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
```

For the *Select All* to only work for the currently filtered items, first, use the `hidden` class instead of using the `style` attribute. This will make it easier to not select the hidden items:

```js
a[i].classList.toggle('hidden', txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1);
```

Then when toggling the *Select All* checkbox, select checkbox `<input>` elements that are not hidden:

```js
var ele = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.hidden) > div > input[type=checkbox]");
```

Putting it all together:

```js
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  console.log(filter);
  div = document.getElementById("getMerchant");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    a[i].classList.toggle('hidden', txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1);
  }
}

function selectAll() {
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll("li:not(.hidden) > div > input[type=checkbox]");
  var checked = $('#checkbox-item-14').is(':checked');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    ele[i].checked = checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-3gJwYpMe3QewGELv8k/BX9vcqhryRdzRMxVfq6ngyWXwo03GFEzjsUm8Q7RZcHPHksttq7/GFoxjCVUjkjvPdw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="dropdownSearch" class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow w-60" style="z-index: 999;">
  <div class="p-3">
    <label for="input-group-search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 4a4 4 0 100 8 4 4 0 000-8zM2 8a6 6 0 1110.89 3.476l4.817 4.817a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4.816-4.816A6 6 0 012 8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5 " placeholder="Search user">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="getMerchant" class="h-48 px-3 pb-3 overflow-y-auto text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownSearchButton">
    <li>
      <div class="flex items-center p-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
        <input id="checkbox-item-14" onchange="selectAll()" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500">
        <label for="checkbox-item-14" id="select_all" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded dark:text-gray-300">Select All</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="flex items-center p-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 ">
        <input id="merchant" name="merchant[]" type="checkbox" value="foo" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 ">
        <label for="merchant-checkbox" id="merchant_name" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded ">foo</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="flex items-center p-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 ">
        <input id="merchant" name="merchant[]" type="checkbox" value="bar" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 ">
        <label for="merchant-checkbox" id="merchant_name" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded ">bar</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="flex items-center p-2 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 ">
        <input id="merchant" name="merchant[]" type="checkbox" value="baz" class="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 ">
        <label for="merchant-checkbox" id="merchant_name" class="w-full ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 rounded ">baz</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```